# Finding RHS of combinatorial proof: $n^2=(n-2)^2+2(n-2)+2n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs

The identity: $n^2=(n-2)^2+2(n-2)+2n$

The question that I’m answering is “how many lists of length 2 on n elements are there.”

LHS is fairly obvious in terms of answering the question, but I’m not sure how to answer the RHS, combinatorially.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Draw an $(n-2)×(n-2)$ square. Then add two rows of length $n-2$ each, to the top of the $(n-2)×(n-2)$ square, to get a $(n-2)×n$ rectangle. Then add $2$ columns of length $n$ each, to the right of the $(n-2)×n$ rectangle to get an $n×n$ square....

Answer (score 0):

Let the elements be $\{1,\dots,n\}$, and consider three disjoint cases:

- The list contains neither $n-1$ nor $n$.
- The list contains exactly one of $\{n-1,n\}$ and in the first position.
- The list contains either $n-1$ or $n$ in the second position.